# SQL Command error: Incorrect syntax near '4'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get a "Incorrect syntax near '4'." while executing this command :

```
 @"SELECT * FROM [Table] OFFSET 4 LIMIT 2;"
```

what is the probem here?

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: Not sure how to get the version, but I'm using Visual studio express 2015

Comment: it may be MySQL or PostgreSQL

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar: It is SQL-Server. Look at the`[]`

Comment: you cannot use LIMIT and OFFSET in SQL-Server. USE TOP instead

Comment: so how do I get N rows starting from a to b?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TOP'.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL SELECT TOP Clause
The SELECT TOP clause is used to specify the number of records to return.

The SELECT TOP clause is useful on large tables with thousands of records. Returning a large number of records can impact on performance.

> Note: Not all database systems support the SELECT TOP clause. MySQL
>   supports the LIMIT clause to select a limited number of records, while
>   Oracle uses ROWNUM.

SQL Server / MS Access Syntax:

```
SELECT TOP number|percent column_name(s)
  FROM table_name
 WHERE condition;
```

Example

```
SELECT TOP 2 * 
  FROM [Table]
```

Comment: how to start from the 5th row or something?

Comment: the number beside TOP determines how many rows only

Answer (score 0):

There is no `LIMIT` in SQL Server.  You use `FETCH`:

Without an `ORDER BY`, the `OFFSET` is meaningless, so you can just do

```
SELECT TOP 2 t.*
FROM [Table] t;
```

If you do have an `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM [Table] t
ORDER BY ?
OFFSET 4 ROWS FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY;
```

The `?` is a placeholder for the name of the column you want to sort by.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near '?'. Invalid usage of the option FIRST in the FETCH statement.

Comment: @"SELECT * FROM [Table] ORDER BY [ID] OFFSET 4 ROWS FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY;"